# Route53 not updating, can't understand Amazon's NS

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services

I changed the IP value for an A record on Route53, and it hasn't propagating since one week ago.

I can't understand why if I dig the domain I get:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
prodosecall.com.        170599  IN      NS      ns-583.awsdns-08.net.
prodosecall.com.        170599  IN      NS      ns-467.awsdns-58.com.
prodosecall.com.        170599  IN      NS      ns-1880.awsdns-43.co.uk.
prodosecall.com.        170599  IN      NS      ns-1383.awsdns-44.org.
```

while the NS in my panel are:

```
ns-1238.awsdns-26.org
ns-388.awsdns-48.com
ns-584.awsdns-09.net
ns-1655.awsdns-14.co.uk
```

Obviously if I run:

```
dig @ns-1238.awsdns-26.org <nameofmydomain>
```

I get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring because the name servers you are using are not authoritative.  According to WHOIS records for the domain name, the authoritative servers are currently:

```
   Name Server: NS-1383.AWSDNS-44.ORG
   Name Server: NS-1880.AWSDNS-43.CO.UK
   Name Server: NS-467.AWSDNS-58.COM
   Name Server: NS-583.AWSDNS-08.NET
```